# How to Design a UI to enter Business Rules

Tags: rules

In my current Project we have a UI, where Business analysts write down rules to transform database columns, which Programmers pick up and then code it using COBOL.

I'm working with my team to transform this UI so that we can automate this process so that we can minimize most of the coding exercise as most of the rules are pretty simple, for ex: Mapping values based on another column, Date Formatting, CASE/IF-THEN-ELSE types.

Before building something from scratch I wanted to make sure that there isn't something which can help us, (tool/framework).

Please suggest

Details: We are trying to develop as a desktop application, Windows Standalone application, using c# or Dot net.

Answer (score -1):

There are things called rules engine. You can check out for something like Dro

Comment: Do you mean Drools?

Comment: Look like you are not using Java technology, so you may want to build a separate web service to handle your rules.

Comment: forgot to mention, we are looking for option with thick clients, preferable windows standalone applications